# Loose focus after click and get focus on TAB key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue related to a button's focus and active state.
So here is the scenario.

I have a button like as follows.

```
<button class="floating_button">
   <svg>.....</svg>
</button>
```

as it is mentioned there is an SVG content inside the button tags.

I have applied the following CSS:

```
.floating_button:focus{
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
.floating_button:active{
  transform: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

So here I want to get two things done.

1. When I click on the button (in active state) it should not scale the button 
   by 1.1, it should behave like a normal button.
2. When I press the tab key from the keyboard the scale should take place as the 
   the button will get in Focus state.

The problem I am facing is as soon as I click the button it stays scaled until I click anywhere in the window.

How do I stop this and achieve the above accessibility?

I have also one bonus question.

Is it possible to focus different divs by their class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the button take its focus away (ideally, call `focus()` for the logical next element) when it is triggered (`onclick` event). This way, it will not gain focus when clicked via mouse (because focus is gained through click itself), but will retain focus state when navigated to via Tab.

```css
.floating_button:focus {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
.floating_button:active {
  transform: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input tabindex />
<br>
<button class="floating_button" tabindex onclick="this.blur()">
   <svg width="40" height="40">
    <circle r="16" cx="20" cy="20" fill="black"/>
   </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks :) @YellowAfterlife